# LinkedIn API: How to get company from status-update link?

Tags: linkedin-api

I have just one basic question about the LinkedIn API, I'm new to that and I don't even use LinkedIn.

Imagine that I have this link: https://www.linkedin.com/nhome/updates?topic=5967002483262787584 - how can I restore the company ID, updateKey for the company or something similar to that? Simply I want to get any information and I know how to use the company API but this is a bit problem (that cannot be solved by this API) and I don't know how to solve that...

Thanks a lot for every single help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - First take a look at this information:

[How to get company logo from Linkedin API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749227/how-to-get-large-company-logo-from-linkedin-api/34749453#34749453)

Then take a look at this web page:

https://www.linkedin.com/nhome/updates?topic=5967002483262787584

The other problem is similar to your problem.  You will have to scrape the web page to get the information.  If you look at the <TITLE>...</TITILE> part on the IBM web page you will see it says "IBM | LinkedIn".

That is how you get the company's name off of the web page's HTML.

The LinkedIn API says:

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/company-profile

Check out their Profile Information.  Note the "name" field? The company's name should be in that field also.

(BTW: I do NOT work for Stack Overflow or LinkedIn. Just in case you were wondering. I'm just a good samaritan helping out. :-) )

Update: I just re-read your request.  If you know what the company's name is you should be able to use the API to reload their profile which has their ID number on it.  Don't know about an update key.  Do you get what I am talking about?